# jQuery ajax data retrieve and append

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, comments

Dead stackoverflow community,

I am currently working on a comment system project. I use jQuery ajax to call data, as well as using PDO in PHP database scripting. I am able to store the comments into the database, and when I refresh the page, I can see the comments listed out fine. The thing is I can't "append" the comment right after clikcing Post comments, in the console, it stats

```
"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error <div class="comment"> <p class="name"><--The user that has just commented--></p><p class="comment"><--Their Comment--></p>
```

"

I know I am very close, can anyone plase help me out? I have been struggling for almost 2 days now. The following are the three pieces of codes:

index page form:

```
<form id="form" method="post' "class="comment">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>" />
                <textarea name="comment" class="newComment" rows="6" placeholder="Comment..." required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" class="cSubmit" value="Post Comment" />
                <div class="cancelBt">Cancel</div> </form><div class="allComments" />
```

ajax requrest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var form = $('form');
            var submit = $('.cSubmit');

            form.on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax_comment.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    cache: false,
                    data: form.serialize(), //form serizlize data
                    beforeSend: function(){

                        submit.val('Submitting...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    },
                    success: function(data) {

                        var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
                        $('.allComments').append(item);


                        form.trigger('reset');
                        submit.val('Post Comment').removeAttr('disabled');
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        alert(e);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

and finally the ajax file:

```
<?php if (isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] )):
require_once ("newconfig.php");

if(!empty($_POST['post_id']) AND !empty($_POST['user_id']) AND !empty($_POST['comment'])) {

    $artwork_id = ($_POST['post_id']);
    $user_id = ($_POST['user_id']);
    $comment = ($_POST['comment']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`post_id`, `user_id`, `comment`) VALUES (:pid, :uid, :cmt)";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    try {
        $stmt->bindValue(":pid", $post_id);
        $stmt->bindValue(":uid", $user_id);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cmt", $comment);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }   
} ?>
<div class="comment">
<p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $user_id;?></p>
<p class="comment"><?php echo $comment;?></p>
```

s

Thank you for taking the time to read my codes, I think my problem is retrieving data off from the ajax file back into the index file, that is why I cant append the data I want, but I am not too sure how to fix it. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the below line, where the data sent from the server is `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error <div class="comment">  <p class="name"><--The user that has just commented--></p><p class="comment"><--Their Comment--></p>`

```
var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
```

Then it creates an invalid jQuery selector, what you are really trying to do is to create elements and display them so

```
var item = $('<div />', {
    html: data
}).hide().appendTo('.allComments').fadeIn(800);
```

Comment: So the problem is having an invalid jQuery selector?

How do I replace the "$('<div />',"  in your answer in my index page with the <div> I want from the ajax file?

Comment: @RayWai it will be better if you can share the value of `data`... the ajax response

Comment: Hi, @Arun P Johny
The value of the data in the ajax I want to get is exactly the error I see in the output of the console when I press the submit button and send out the user's comments. I want the following 'new comment'
" <div class="comment"> <p class="name"><--The user that has just commented--></p><p class="comment"><--Their Comment--></p>" to be appended to my other older comments.

Comment: @RayWai it seems to be working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8np4f1zb/2/

Comment: The problem is my desire output will be in a separate ajax file. After registering the post_id, user_id, and comment, I want that very same information to be displayed back into the index file. How can I refer that "new comment" <div> from ajax file into the index file item variable under the javascript as you presented?

Comment: the code in fiddle looks to be working... but the thing is I do not know how to make it into my code